# Run an artisan command from a Laravel app

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel's artisan can be used to execute many tasks including migrations, generation of resources...etc.

In Laravel 4, how could you run an artisan command from you app without using `shell_exec`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You run Artisan commands via `Artisan::call`, for example:

```
Artisan::call('migrate')
```

Comment: Old question, but here's a way to get artisan output with **Laravel 5.7**: `$output = new BufferedOutput; $code = Artisan::call('migrate', array(), $output); return ['output' => $output->fetch(), 'code' => $code];`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get command output:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;

class MyClass 
{
    public function myFunc()
    {
        $stream = fopen("php://output", "w");

        Artisan::call('my-command', array(), new StreamOutput($stream));

        var_dump($stream);
    }

}
```